# Partial Differential of L1 Norm

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Partial Differentiation of L1 norm if p=1:

> The partial derivative of the $p$-norm is given by
> $$
> \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{k}}\|\mathbf{x}\|_{p}=\frac{x_{k}\left|x_{k}\right|^{p-2}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|_{p}^{p-1}} .
> $$
> The derivative with respect to $x$, therefore, is
> $$
> \frac{\partial\|\mathbf{x}\|_{p}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}=\frac{\mathbf{x} \circ|\mathbf{x}|^{p-2}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|_{p}^{p-1}}
> $$

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b375.png), Source Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)

My Question::

When I consider p=1, as I want the L1 norm, here the things got confusing with the denominator part.

The Denominator Part ::
$\Vert x\Vert^0_{1}$

As I know from Basic Mathematics, something to the power is equal to 1 [example: $(a)^0=1$]. So what will be the case for the above denominator that I am confused in? Can anyone help me? I need to understand so that I can write the MatLab code from it.

Answer (score 1):

The $\ell_{1}$ norm is $\Vert x\Vert_{1}=|x_{1}|+\cdots+|x_{n}|$.
For brevity, define $\partial_{k}\equiv\partial/\partial x_{k}$.
If $x_{k}$ is positive, then $\partial_{k}\Vert x\Vert_{1}=1$.
If $x_{k}$ is negative, then, $\partial_{k}\Vert x\Vert_{1}=-1$.
If $x_{k}$ is zero, then $\partial_{k}\Vert x\Vert_{1}$ does not exist.
Therefore, assuming none of the components of the vector $x$ are
zero, the gradient is $\nabla\Vert x\Vert_{1}=\operatorname{sign}(x)$.

Note that this is consistent with the formula from Wikipedia for $p=1$:
$$
\frac{x_{k}|x_{k}|^{1-2}}{\Vert x\Vert_{1}^{1-1}}=\frac{x_{k}|x_{k}|^{-1}}{\Vert x\Vert_{1}^{0}}=\frac{x_{k}}{|x_{k}|}=\begin{cases}
\text{undefined} & \text{if }x_k=0\\
\operatorname{sign}(x_{k}) & \text{if }x_k\neq0.
\end{cases}
$$